# how can I place the rtl text next to the ltr text with the same height in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

how can I place the rtl text next to the ltr text with the same height
result:

[image: result:]

my code:

```
 Text(
            widget.myNotes.title,
            maxLines: 1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
```

[Full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYCI5.png)

Comment: Maybe you can wrap the Row with Container and provide red. Also RichText widget maybe solve this issue, not sure

Comment: @Sahand you want to set background for both text in same shape?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: @eamirho3ein I want to remove the extra padding, the Persian and English text have the same height

Comment: Can you include full snippet for attached image

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I attached the image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving text background color, wrap the text inside a container and give the container your desired color.

For the same height you have to use custom fonts that matches the height in both English and Urudu i think there are no other way of bringing the height down.

[image: see result]

```
  Wrap(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          spacing: 8,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: const Text(
                'First اول',
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: const Text(
                'Second دوم',
              ),
            ),
            const Text(
              '2022/12/18 15:06',
            ),
          ],
        ),
```